# how to write a script in linux for login into several serval one by one and fetch their description?

Tags: shell, authentication, server, fetch

how to write a script in linux to login into several serval one by one and fetch their description ?
I am learning shell scripting, tried few commands but not able to arrange logic into code.

Answer (score 0):

As my question gives a wide range and possiblities to think,so to be exact I want to create a script that opens a file in /tmp name as 'list' which contains many IP addresses, Then I have to login in those IP's one by one by ssh command and for loop and then after logging in by using awk command I want to fetch 7th column which gives info about server.

I am just on intial stage of shell scripting donot ahve that understanding,

I tried below command but this didn't worked out for me.

for line in `cat /tmp/list`
do
echo $i
echo "***********"
ssh $i |grep tsm |awk -F : '{print $7, "\t", $1}'
echo
done